# JNLP Parse exception

Tags: java, apache, jnlp

I am seeing below errors in java console when trying to launch an applet. We are running on Apache 2.2 and WebSphere application server 7.0.0.27. any pointers please?

```
JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 26.]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.throwNewException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 26.], bail out
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat tool for checking jnlp errors: JaNeLA (available on my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have verified the syntax using JaNeLa as weel and it does not complain about any error. Interestingly the error says line 26 whereas the jnlp closes even before that and no line 26 exist.

Comment: As the author of JaNeLA, I can tell you with confidence that it does not detect *every possible error.*  Are there any non UTF-8 characters in the file?  Can you show it exactly as it appears to the client as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21263030/edit)?  Note that the reporting on JNLP problems is less than ideal.  It often happens that an error occurs much earlier in a file than what the output says.

Comment: I have to admit I don't fully understand your comment. In the first sentence you say: "it does not complain about any error" and in the 2nd sentence you state "the error says". So what is the case? Is there an error or not? So why don't you post your jnlp file here? Otherwise it is just guessing around...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Exception, you have a XML Syntax error in your jnlp file.

You could use a XML Editor to validate the file (as [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net)). Also you can put the JNLP file in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have verified the syntax and it does not complain about any error. Interestingly the error says line 26 whereas the jnlp closes even before that and no line 26 exist.

Comment: Are you sure you are verifying the same file that the applet is loading? Pehaps the exception is showing line 26 because it isn't the same file.